# folder(URL only) to file redirect while keeping URL intact (htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

well, i'm not sure how to explain this.

i got multiple files under the root directory of my website like; a.html, b.html, c.html

what i'm trying to achieve is to be able to redirect http://domain.com/answers/ to a.html while keeping the URL intact, as http://domain.com/answers/ .

i am able to redirect directories to these files by simple redirects, but that does not keep the URL intact.

can these two be done by htaccess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're looking at basic URL rewriting.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule   ^answers/?$   a.html  [NC]
```

Comment: mhm. that was quite easy, thanks. however, there i still have a problem, http://domain.com/answers works fine but http://domain.com/answers/ does not show up properly. (the images etc. do not show up) - as if the image/css paths should be updated? is this normal?

Comment: If images in your a.html file were relative (e.g: pointing to something like "../images/mypic.jpg" you would need to to adjust to paths or rewrite path altogether. but first option is easier: just point images to an absolute path: "/images/mypic.jpg"

Comment: that is domain.com/answers / , not working - the site seems to removed the slash at the end(showing as URL without that last slash).